# Byte skipping when casting occurs

Tags: c++, struct, byte, field

I have a struct that looks like this

```
struct message_header
{
    unsigned long msg_num : 32;            //0-3    message id
    unsigned long msg_len : 32;            //4-7    message length
    unsigned long hardware_version : 16;   //8-9    hardware version
    unsigned long sender_location : 32     //10-13  location
    unsigned long message;                 //14 ... messages
};

message_header * msg_ptr;
```

After receiving the character array (`recvbuf`) from `recvfrom` function, i will do
`reinterpret_cast`,

`msg_ptr = reinterpret_cast<message_header*>(recvbuf)`

However, after my simulator (from linux, VM) sends the data, and my receiver (the struct is in the receiver) (on windows), the output data does not tally.

Assuming the data send from the simulator is:

`msg num : 1010`
`msg len : 20`
`hardware version: 1`
`location: 25`
`messages: //rest of the bytes`

Packets from the wireshark shows:

`00 00 03 F2`
`00 00 00 14`
`00 01 00 00`
`00 19 00 00`
`...`

The output print is:

`msg num : 1010`
`msg len : 20`
`hardware version: 1`
`location: 1638400`

After much debugging, I noticed that during the cast, after hardware version, the `00 00` after the `01` was either discarded, or skipped, i am not sure which as I can't find a way to determine it, and the next 4 bytes of `00 19 00 00` was cast into my `sender_location`.

All the message types and length, from the sender is build base on the sender's design specification, and the `hardware version` on the sender is an `unsigned short`.

I have read up on the following question and answers

[Fields in a struct skipping bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513239/fields-in-a-struct-skipping-bytes/3513340#3513340)

[#pragma pack effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect)

And i have tried but to no avail, please advise.

Comment: Are you using an old compiler that doesn't support [C99 fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) or can pack structures? Is there some other reason you have a bitfield?

Comment: I am using VS 2015, and i am using bitfield to limit on the amount of bytes getting cast into the per variables, i am a junior programmer and using bitfield is "recommended" by my senior, i was initially using memcpy per field but was told that casting it into a struct would be less complicated.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to allocate the message structure separately and then using `memcpy` to copy the data (the whole structure)?

Comment: gonna try that now and let you know the result

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, memcpy, works just fine

Comment: Then I suggest you use that for now, while you try to figure out why the casting doesn't seem to work (it should, if the buffer is large enough and you don't modify it directly any other way).

Comment: i will have to change my entire class, which might be a bit of work, and yes, i do not understand why are my bytes discarded, or not being cast into the variables as well.

Comment: Have you checked that the data in the buffer right after you received it is correct? Have you checked the data in the buffer directly before the cast? If it's correct at either point then it might be a compiler bug. If the data is incorrect when cast it, but correct when receive it, then it's modified somewhere between and you have to look at that code. It could also be problems with threads overwriting data perhaps? There could be thousands of reasons behind the problem, but without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to say more.

Comment: Yes, i have verified when the message arrives on the machine, via wireshark, that they are correct, i have checked byte by byte myself to make sure what i sent from the simulator sender is correct, and i have printed the entire character array out, in hex form, from the `recvfrom` function, to make sure it is correct as well, and this is when i noticed that my `00 00` were skipped/discarded.

Comment: You should look into how to mock a program and post it as a [mcve]. Chances are, you will have found the problem while doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of n or a multiple of the size of the member, whichever is smaller.

I did not understand what this means at first, till i re-read over and over again, i realize that my `hardware version` is using a `long` of `4 bytes`, rather than i should be using a `short` of `2 bytes` instead, another question comes to mind, which is why is the bitfield limitation not working, or i  may have understand it wrongly.

So after changing it from `long` to `short`, and with `#pragma pack(1)`, the cast works fine now.

And how i found out was by using `offsetof` function to check

`cout << offsetof (message_header, msg_num) << endl;`
`cout << offsetof (message_header, msg_len) << endl;`
`cout << offsetof (message_header, hardware_version) << endl;`
`cout << offsetof (message_header, sender_location ) << endl;`
`cout << offsetof (message_header, message) << endl;`

And the printout is, then i realize the bitfield was not working at all.
`0`
`4`
`8`
`12`
`16`

After changing `hardware_version`, from `long` to `short`, AND without `#pragma pack(1)`, the printout is still similar to the one above, however, once `#pragma pack(1)` is enabled, the printout is

`0`
`4`
`6`
`10`
`14`